# Is there something unique that identifies a computer from others?

Tags: hard-drive, mac-address

I'm developing an application and I need to identify all computers that I encounter.

Is there a certain technology to identify a computer?

Is it the hard disk serial number?

Comment: See [this question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986732/how-to-get-a-unique-computer-identifier-in-java-like-disk-id-or-motherboard-id) (it says Java but the answers are general). It also depends on what you're doing. For instance, configuration management systems often generate certificates to identify computers.

Comment: thanks a lot , I got the answer for my situation I should use the MAC Address of the network card :)

Comment: Hard disk have serial numbers, USB devices have serial numbers.  There are manual devices on a system that have a (theoretically) unique ID.

Comment: @HadyHallak - MAC address can be changed.

Comment: Not *changed*, spoofed... The real MAC is still there, it's just hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your earliest PC's did not store unique identifying information anywhere.  Of course, as PC's have evovled, serial numbers have been introduced into more and more things.

- The burned-in MAC address of any network cards (The burned-in MAC cannot be changed)
- The serial number of any hard drives
- A serial number is encoded into RAM modules [Serial Presence Detect (SPD) EEPROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Presence_Detect) that can be read over the I2c bus.
- Intel introduced a processor serial number, which can be queried with `CPUID`, around the time of the Pentium III.  [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpuid) seems to say it's no longer present on CPUs.
- Keys derived from the TPM endorsement (root) key ought to be unique
- [SMBIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS) stores a motherboard serial number
- Many PCI and USB peripherals store some sort of serial number accessible in some manner.

Answer (score 0):

Computers manufactured in the last decade should have a UUID. Its the Universally Unique Identifier. MAC is good and all, but UUID is specific to a computer.

According to PCMag.com:

> (Universally Unique ID) A unique number generated for any purpose, but
>   that cannot be accidentally duplicated by another party and wind up in
>   conflict later on. The UUID is a 128-bit number that is so large that
>   it is infinite for all intents and purposes; however, there are
>   different algorithms used to create it. The original algorithm uses
>   the MAC address of the Ethernet adapter in the machine and the time of
>   day. Subsequent versions use similar and dissimilar methods for
>   computing the number. See GUID and OID.

Using Powershell you can discover the UUID of a remote system.

> get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct -computername RANTPC | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UUID

replace -computername with the hostname obviously.